# How to make an EMV card from a Javacard?

Tags: javacard, emv

I'm going to write a Java Card applet to convert my card into an EMV compliant card.

**1- The question is how can I do that?**

As far as I know, there are four EMV specifications known as EMV Books which contain principles of EMV cards (Chip characteristics, file structure and also the list of APDU commands). Do I need any other specifications to implement my applet or these are all I need? If there are some other specifications which I need, are they freely available or they are proprietary?

**2- Do EMV cards have an specific Applet AID?**

[EFT-Lab](https://www.eftlab.com/knowledge-base/211-emv-aid-rid-pix/) provided a good list of applet AIDs. As you see below, there are a lot of AIDs which belong to Visa International (as vendors) that all are "EMV" types. Why does Visa International have a lot of different AIDs for its EMV applets? What's the difference between these applets?

[image]

**3- Is there any open source EMV applet? Is there any Java Card that has an EMV applet/package by default?**

**4- Is there any specific difference between contact and contactless EMV cards? (I mean in the file-structure or in the APDU commands)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1- The question is how can I do that?

Yes. Implement the specifications. If there are any other requirements (and surely there will be) then they should be referenced in the specs.

> 2- Do EMV cards have an specific Applet AID?

Because they offer specific functionality? You may even have multiple applications on the same card. Note that it is possible to select applications using a partial AID (see how the Debit & Credit card partially match). The VISA specific cards are likely used internally only, e.g. when servicing cash machines.

> 3- Is there any open source EMV applet? Is there any Java Card that has an EMV applet/package by default?

Not likely. It would be rather unusable because it would require [EMVCo security evaluation](https://www.emvco.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/EMVCo-SEWG-14-P02-V5-1_EMVCo_Security_Evaluation_Process_20160725082101992.pdf) to be accepted. So you need some kind of payment structure to pay for certification and audits. No open source initiative is likely to pony up the cash up front.

Often these kind of implementations require techniques to avoid vulnerabilities that need to remain secret; smart cards do not offer perfect security after all. That's perpendicular to open sourcing an implementation. So if there is anything out there it must be created out of academic interest (e.g. for testing the security of the protocol, proof of concept etc.).

> 4- Is there any specific difference between contact and contactless EMV cards? (I mean in the file-structure or in the APDU commands)

Generally it is more about which parts of the applet are available or not. The fact that most applets can be used in dual mode probably speaks for itself otherwise.

[This paper](https://www.cs.ru.nl/E.Poll/papers/EMVtechreport.pdf) seems to have a good introduction to the possible differences.

Comment: Thank you dear Maarten. Let assume that I have wrote an application on my card to convert it to an EMV card. And also let assume that I have registered AID of this applet. The question is that "How the  POS/ATM applications can select my applet without knowing the AID?". Am I need to request POS/ATM developers to hardcode my applet's AID In their applications?

Comment: Probably  yes, because generally you'd use one of the EMV ones you've indicated. The AID reflects the protocol rather than the issuer.

Comment: 'Not likely. It would be rather unusable because it would require EMVCo security evaluation to be accepted.' -- do you know how to use google? I found at least two implementations. https://github.com/JavaCardOS/OpenEMV .... as for usability, these are mainly for testing. Moreover, some services (public transport in our city) support **any** payment card to put your pre-paid ticket on. Instead of having it on a debit card and losing the card in months...

Comment: Btw there are also nice lists of opensource javacard stuff such as [JavaCard curated list](https://github.com/EnigmaBridge/javacard-curated-list) for applet SW searches.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any open source EMV applet? Is there any Java Card that has
> an EMV applet/package by default?

Was working on a similar project and found [this](https://github.com/tiosolid/emv_applet) github repo. According to the owner:

> This is a fully working EMV applet for javacard 2.2.1.
> Hope this helps.